# Will updating chrome on ubuntu clear my browser data, cookies, session storage etc?

Tags: 18.04, updates, google-chrome

I want to update my chrome on ubuntu.

Will it clear my cookies, session and other data of some particular link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your cookies, cache, and site-specific data will remain, as well as all the [cached .js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files).

In general, it's best to let the system handle your updates, unless you have something special you absolutely, positively, utterly, need the very latest shiny version for.  Chrome's an exception, since you originally installed it by downloading the installer from Google's website (it's not in the [list of packages for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages)).

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414 says *Linux users: To update Google Chrome, use your package manager.*

Comment: can you tell me how i can update @K7AAY

Comment: See the last paragraph  above.

Answer (score 0):

It did for me (on Chromium), but only because since Ubuntu 19.10, Chromium comes as  a snap instead of a deb, meaning the location of cookies, history, user sign-ins, extensions, etc. is now at `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default` instead of `~/.config/chromium/Default`. Copying that folder over makes all things I listed appear again in Chromium.